# Button to change boolean to true or false; not always false?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have code for a button that sets a boolean named ProjectCompleteOrgBtn.

I am trying to make this button set the boolean to true if you click it, then if you click it again after it makes it false, then again true, repeat.

The true and false sort the form below differently. Though at the moment everytime you click the button, it is always true. How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub ProjectCompleteOrgBtn_Click()

Dim ProjectCompeleteOrgB As Boolean

If ProjectCompleteOrgB = True Then
Set ProjectCompleteOrgB = False
Else
Set ProjectCompleteOrgB = True



If ProjectCompleteOrgB = False Then

MsgBox (False)
Forms!DatabaseF.ProjectQSubF.Form.RecordSource = "Select * from ProjectsQ ORDER BY ProjectComplete ASC"
Forms!DatabaseF.ProjectQSubF.Form.Refresh

Else

MsgBox (True)
Forms!DatabaseF.ProjectQSubF.Form.RecordSource = "Select * from ProjectsQ ORDER BY ProjectComplete DESC "
Forms!DatabaseF.ProjectQSubF.Form.Refresh
ProjectCompleteOrgB = False

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do

```
Dim ProjectCompeleteOrgB As Boolean
```

but notice it is spelled wrong (CompElete).

Then you write

```
If ProjectCompleteOrgB = False Then
```

but your code only changes that property or variable's value in the `True` block of your `If`. It doesn't get changed anywhere else.

Furthermore, you can make this:

```
If ProjectComplete = True Then
Set ProjectComplete = False
Else
Set ProjectComplete = True
```

much shorter by just writing

```
ProjectComplete = Not ProjectComplete
```

Comment: I am sorry, I messed the code up while writing it again here on the site. I fixed it above. All ProjectCompeletes that aren't in the sort should have been ProjectCompleteOrgB.

Comment: What I think I need to do is store the data of the boolean's value somewhere, as every time you click the button it resets the value as 0; and does the same thing over adn over again instead of the opposite every time.

Comment: You mean you haven't defined `ProjectCompleteOrgB` as a property of your form??

Comment: See, this is why Visual Basic sucks so much. Please add `Option Explicit On` to your form, as its very first line, then you will get notified when a variable hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: No, I was trying to do it all inside of the code for onclick. Though now that I think about it, I don't think that is possible is it? I'm going to need to throw down a checkbox or something, correct?

Comment: Store the boolean value not in a local variable, but a `Property` on the form. Otherwise it will just never work.

Comment: In the Tag property under the form?

Comment: Blasphemy! @RoyDictus Visual Basic is the best!

Comment: @user2915607: No, create your own Property (see http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3402), or at least make it a "global variable".